# File upload issue with HttpMime and UniRest client

Tags: java, api, file-upload, unirest

**Problem**

Getting `NoSuchMethosError` while uploading the file using `httmmime` and `Unirest`. I have a project and framework, `httpclient` and `httpcore` dependencies are there in the framework and `httpmime` is in the project.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)V
```

And if I import both project and framwork into eclipse workspace, file upload works fine and if i just import project and user framework jar in classpath then i am getting the error.

Same error I am getting in Jenkins also.

**Solutions I have tried:**

1. Added both `httpmine` and `httpclient` in the project.
2. Excluded the `httpclient` and `httpcore` dependencies from the framework and added `httpmime`, `httpclient` and `httpcore` dependencies in the project.
3. Tried with all possible versions of `httpmime`, `httpclient` and `httpcore`.
   Nothing worked for me.

Comment: You have a version mismatch. what version are you using for each artifact?

Comment: @FranMontero, I am using httpmime 4.5.3 and httpclient 4.5.1

Comment: I have tried with all possibe versions of httpmime and httpclient